# Put two columns into box

Tags: vertical-alignment, multicol, multicolumn

I wish to produce a PDF output like this :

[image]

The closest I got so far was by using the `multicols` environment,
as shown below. As you can see, the line contour of the box around
the two columns is missing, and I have no idea how to implement it.
Any help appreciated.

[image]

The source code :

```
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\bigskip

\centerline{\huge XXXXXXX}

\bigskip

\setlength{\columnseprule}{1pt}
\def\columnseprulecolor{\color{green}}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\ \newline

\centerline{\Large XXXXXXXXXX}
\bigskip

\ \newline
XXXX-xxxx : \'El\`eve \`a XXXX xxxx \newline
 \ \newline
XXXX-xxxx :  \'El\`eve en MPSI puis MP* au Lyc\'ee Xxxxxxx \`a Xxxxxx
 \bigskip
 \ \newline
 \bigskip
  \bigskip 
\columnbreak
\ \newline

\centerline{\Large XXXXXXXXX}
\bigskip

\noindent xx/xx/xxx : Soutenu la th\`ese de doctorat "Xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxx xxx xxxxxxxxx xx xxxxxxx-xxxxxx", obtenu avec la mention tr\`es honorable \newline
 \ \newline
xxxx : Re\c{c}u xxi\`eme \`a xxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxx xx xxxxxxxxxxxx \newline
 \ \newline
xxxx : Xxx x, xxxx Xxxxx xxxx \newline
\end{multicols}

\bigskip

  Xxxx xxxx xxx xxx xx x xxxx x x, xxx x xx  x; xxx.


\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you want  the blue frame around the two columns? B.t.w., you can type accented letters. ‘Élève’ is much easier to read…

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By using the package `tcolorbox`, this can be achieved:

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{empty}

\bigskip

\centerline{\huge XXXXXXX}

\bigskip

\setlength{\columnseprule}{1pt}
\def\columnseprulecolor{\color{green}}

\begin{tcolorbox}[
sharp corners=all,
colback=white,
colframe=green,
size=tight,
boxrule=1mm,
left=3mm,right=3mm
]
{\begin{multicols}{2}
\ \newline


\centerline{\Large XXXXXXXXXX}
\bigskip

\ \newline
XXXX-xxxx : \'El\`eve \`a XXXX xxxx \newline
 \ \newline
XXXX-xxxx :  \'El\`eve en MPSI puis MP* au Lyc\'ee Xxxxxxx \`a Xxxxxx
 \bigskip
 \ \newline
 \bigskip
  \bigskip 
\columnbreak
\ \newline

\centerline{\Large XXXXXXXXX}
\bigskip

\noindent xx/xx/xxx : Soutenu la th\`ese de doctorat "Xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxx xxx xxxxxxxxx xx xxxxxxx-xxxxxx", obtenu avec la mention tr\`es honorable \newline
 \ \newline
xxxx : Re\c{c}u xxi\`eme \`a xxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxx xx xxxxxxxxxxxx \newline
 \ \newline
xxxx : Xxx x, xxxx Xxxxx xxxx \newline
\end{multicols}}
\end{tcolorbox}

\bigskip

  Xxxx xxxx xxx xxx xx x xxxx x x, xxx x xx  x; xxx.


\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
\begin{multicols}{3}
\begin{tcolorbox}[width=1\linewidth, halign=center, colframe=blue, colback=blue!30, boxsep=5mm, arc=3mm]
Here is some text
\end{tcolorbox} 
\columnbreak
\begin{tcolorbox}[width=1\linewidth, halign=center, colframe=blue!60, colback=white, boxsep=5mm, arc=3mm]
Here is some text
\end{tcolorbox} 
\columnbreak
\begin{tcolorbox}[width=1\linewidth, halign=center, colframe=blue, colback=blue!30, boxsep=5mm, arc=3mm]
Here is some text
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{multicols}
```

[image: Result]